# data.table: selecting part of a data set on condition in a custom function

Tags: r, function, data.table, subset

I would like to write a function which would select a part of data set using the `data.table` package. The declared parameters of the function are:

- input data set (`dset`),
- variable, on which the data set would be subsetted (`seg.var`),
- value of the declared above variable (`value`).

I was able to write working function in base R:

```
# Function without data.table

data.select <- function(dset, seg.var, value){
  dset.out <- dset[dset[[seg.var]] == value,]
  return(dset.out)
}

data.select(iris, "Species", "setosa")
```

However, I cannot rewrite it with `data.table` package: the function below does not work.

```
# Function with data.table

data.select.dt <- function(dset, seg.var, value){
  dset <- as.data.table(dset)
  dset.out <- dset[seg.var == value,]
  return(dset.out)
}

data.select.dt(iris, Species, "setosa")
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Species' not found

```
data.select.dt(iris, "Species", "setosa")
```

> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width,Species

The input data set is in `data.frame` format. The goal of rewriting above given function is performance improvement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you converting to data.table within the function? You are creating a copy of the whole data set. It would be better to already operate on a `data.table` by converting to a one in place using `setDT`. In either way, I would do a simple binary join. Something like `data.select.dt <- function(dset, seg.var, value) as.data.table(dset)[.(value), on = seg.var]` and then run it as `data.select.dt(iris, "Species", "setosa")`

Comment: I would like to be sure that the rest of the code will work. Since I work with a dataset bigger than `iris`, I would like to compare the performance of "base" subsetting and the one implemented in `data.table` without being forced to rewrite the whole code.

Comment: @kaksat, see the `if(!data.table::is.data.table(dset))` in my answer, should save some time and RAM if `dset` would be a `data.table`.

Comment: If you care about performance, probably best to test that instead of obfuscating via a custom function.

Comment: @m-dz, thanks for this optimization. Nevertheless, I am certain that my data set will be a `data.frame`.

@Frank, at the end of the day I probably will have to make this adjustment, so testing performance with conversion seems reasonable.

Comment: @kaksat, to clarify, `data.frame` syntax will work on a `data.table`, so you can safely use the `setDT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit too long for a comment, so a separate answer:

First, the `get()` function mentioned by me as a comment to @R.S. answer:

```
data.select.dt.V1 <- function(dset, seg.var, value){
  if(!data.table::is.data.table(dset)) dset <- data.table::as.data.table(dset)  # To convert only if needed
  dset[get(seg.var) == value,]
}

data.select.dt.V1(iris, 'Species', 'setosa')
```

And then even more `data.table` function, where you can pass the second argument as an expression (well, in the `data.table` way), not a string:

```
data.select.dt.V2 <- function(dset, seg.var, value){
  if(!data.table::is.data.table(dset)) dset <- data.table::as.data.table(dset)  # To convert only if needed
  sv <- substitute(seg.var)
  dset[eval(sv) == value,]
}

data.select.dt.V2(iris, Species, 'setosa')
```

**Edit:** Functions simplification and test for conversion (thanks to @David Arenburg comment).

**2nd edit:** Benchmarked above two functions with @David Arenburg's one (with and without `is.data.table` check, `V3` and `V4` respectively) on 515 MB `data.table` and `data.frame`:

```
data.select.dt.V3 <- function(dset, seg.var, value) data.table::as.data.table(dset)[.(value), on = seg.var]

data.select.dt.V4 <- function(dset, seg.var, value) {
  if(!data.table::is.data.table(dset)) dset <- data.table::as.data.table(dset)  # To convert only if needed
  dset[.(value), on = seg.var]
}

                                                    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
1 res <- data.select.dt.V1(iris_df, "Species", "setosa") 3.804995 4.585763 4.150130 4.688093 5.320362 3.166503    10   c
2 res <- data.select.dt.V2(iris_df, Species, "setosa")   3.713275 3.827180 3.865347 4.544968 4.753045 3.218075    10   c
3 res <- data.select.dt.V3(iris_df, "Species", "setosa") 1.927947 1.942868 2.167127 2.328364 2.595420 2.159664    10  b 
4 res <- data.select.dt.V4(iris_df, "Species", "setosa") 1.987710 2.004497 2.011502 2.280117 2.856847 1.594249    10  b 

5 res <- data.select.dt.V1(iris_dt, "Species", "setosa") 2.771223 2.792428 2.501362 2.805796 3.056144 1.883520    10  b 
6 res <- data.select.dt.V2(iris_dt, Species, "setosa")   2.830161 2.970071 2.593192 3.123812 3.170884 1.752576    10  b 
7 res <- data.select.dt.V3(iris_dt, "Species", "setosa") 1.963530 2.116116 2.059718 2.203265 2.740949 1.768817    10  b 
8 res <- data.select.dt.V4(iris_dt, "Species", "setosa") 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10 a
```

Clearly `V4` is the one to go if you are expecting both `data.frame` and `data.table`, if only `df` is possible the fastest function would be `V3`.

Answer (score 2):

Check your code:  `dset.out <- dset[seg.var == value,]` in the data.table version should be `dset.out <- dset[dset[[seg.var]] == value,]` which is what you have originally.

`Species` is missing quotation marks, should be `"Species"` when you call the function. That is why the error message says no object `Species` in your workspace.

This works.

```
data.select.dt <- function(dset, seg.var, value){
  dset <- as.data.table(dset)
  dset.out <- dset[dset[[seg.var]] == value,]
  return(dset.out)
}

data.select.dt(iris, "Species", "setosa")
```

Edited to add a tip, debug outside of the function, so you see where things are breaking.

Comment: Or you can use `dset[get(seg.var) == value, ]` to save some time and memory (you are not returning `dset[[seg.var]]`).

Answer (score 1):

There is some subtlety going on here, my recommendation is to break this down into steps. Write the code straight first, then convert to a function:

Your original code works outside of a function:

```
require(data.table)

dset <- as.data.table(iris)
dset.out <- dset[Species == "setosa",]
dset.out
> dset <- as.data.table(iris)
> dset.out <- dset[Species == "setosa",]
> dset.out
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
...
```

however when you wrap it in a function is fails...

```
> require(data.table)
> data.select.dt <- function(dset, seg.var, value){
+   dset <- as.data.table(dset)
+   dset.out <- dset[ seg.var == eval(value) ]
+   return(dset.out)
+ }
> data.select.dt(iris, Species, "setosa")
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Species' not found
```

OK, interesting, why does it fail in the function call? You need to correctly reference the "Species" variable. Which requires you dereference in the call:

```
dset[dset[["Species"]] == "setosa",]
> dset[dset[["Species"]] == "setosa",]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
 ...
```

nb. What I find really interesting is that RStudio in debug allows the function to work, but triggers an error in non-debug mode.

Now you can wrap this in a function:

```
data.select.dt <- function(dset, seg.var, value){
  dset <- as.data.table(dset)
  dset.out <- dset[dset[[seg.var]] == value,]
  return(dset.out)
}
```

Note that the Species is wrapped in quotes `"Species"` ...

```
data.select.dt(iris, "Species", "setosa")

data.select.dt(iris, "Species", "setosa")
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: R.S. gave the correct answer before me